Genexus embeeding Youtube video
En Genexus 17 U11, estoy siguiendo este ejemplo de incrustación de videos de Youtube en el panel de Android:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?21923,HowTo%3A+Embedding+YouTube+videos+in+an+Android+application
Ya obtuve la clave de desarrollador como se explica en el paso 1, pero tengo los siguientes problemas:

Cuando ejecuto la aplicación de Android, tengo el siguiente problema: "Hubo un error inicializando el reproductor de Youtube".

No puedo encontrar la propiedad principal del programa "Clave API de Android Youtube" (en su lugar, estoy usando la API de servicios de Android).


Gracias de antemano.

Hola, Javier. En este sitio se habla español. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para usar el idioma oficial.

El player de youtube usado en v17 dejo de funcionar hace un tiempo.
El mismo se actualizo en Genexus v18 u5 , debes utilizar una version mayor o igual a esta.
Mas info:
https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=53206
